# Opengl ES 2.0 glDeleteFramebuffers after drawing to texture

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, delete-operator, framebuffer

I render to texture using frame buffer. But I am not sure when should I correctly use `glDeleteFramebuffers`. Should fbo exist while texture exists, or can I safely call `glDeleteFramebuffers` after last draw to texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely call glDeleteFramebuffers after the last draw to texture. However, I would work on the assumption that creating and destroying framebuffers is expensive, so I would only do it if I knew for sure I wouldn't be rendering to that texture ever again.

I have experienced bugs on some Android GLES drivers where I've had to detach the texture from the framebuffer prior to deleting the framebuffer so I'd recommend you do that as a precaution:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help and recommendation, I really appreciate it.